# Header alignment gets disturbed when scrollbar gets added in tbody

Tags: css

I have defined two tables for header and and body. i want scrollbar for body when table size is more than 6. but as scrollbar appears alignmnet gets disturbed as scrollbar takes its 16px.and other columnns gets resized.

```
<table id="myProjects" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-scrollable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <table id="myProjects" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-scrollable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

have tried all these css classes, but its not working

#myProjects thead th:last-child {
    width: 161.133px; 
}
*
#myProjects tbody tr:last-child td {
    width: 145.133px; 
}
#myProjects{
    width:924.999px;
}
```

Comment: real question is... why are you defining two tables instead of one??

Comment: You need to define a width of 100%.

Comment: Benjoe, i have tried width as 100% as well, but its not working.

Comment: @Facundo i want to display scrollbar in body section only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 2 different tables, just set the scrollbar on the tbody.

```css
tbody {
  display:block; /*so you can give it a height*/
  overflow-y:auto; /*to show scrollbar*/
  height:100px;
}
thead, tr {
   display:table; /*to restore the table behaviour*/
   table-layout:fixed; /*fix width of table, even columns width*/
   width:100%;
}

thead {white-space: nowrap;}

thead tr:after{
/*creates a "cell" at the end of the header to compensate for the scrollbar width*/
  content:""; width:17px; display:table-cell;
}

td, th{ border:1px solid;}
table{border-collapse:collapse; }
*, *::after{box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Then you have an alignment problem again when you have less rows and the scroll bar is not there.